# How do I connect Namecheap domain to HostGator server?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I'm new to the process of buying domains and hosting packages. I bought a domain at Namecheap and hosting at HostGator.

I'm able to connect to my server via IP address only. I can add files, including index.html to /public_html/. However, my domain still displays this Namecheap placeholder page.

I know I must be missing something. I did all the setup two days ago, and last night I was poking around some more and added some settings on Namecheap so ns1/ns2/ns3/ns4/ns5 is "associated with" my IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your namegator management page. Find the DNS settings for your domain. 
Put in an 'A' record for 'www'. The value you put in should be the IP for your hostgator services. You do *not* want to change your NS entries without an explicit reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

looks like neither your tld, nor your www record, are pointing to hostgator IP addrs (which is why your new box is only accessible by IP).

the fix here is to change your "www" dns record, with namecheap, to point to the IP address assigned to you by hostgator.

details below:

> % whois mdrngrvs.com |grep Name
>     Domain Name: MDRNGRVS.COM
>     Name Server: DNS1.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
>     Name Server: DNS2.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
>     Name Server: DNS3.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
>     Name Server: DNS4.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
>     Name Server: DNS5.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM
>   Registration Service Provided By: Namecheap.com
>
> % dig @DNS1.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM www.mdrngrvs.com  +short
>   free.park-your-domain.com.
>
> % dig @DNS1.REGISTRAR-SERVERS.COM mdrngrvs.com  +short
>   192.31.186.20
>
> % whois park-your-domain.com |grep Name
>     Domain Name: PARK-YOUR-DOMAIN.COM
>     Name Server: DNS1.NAME-SERVICES.COM
>     Name Server: DNS2.NAME-SERVICES.COM
>     Name Server: DNS3.NAME-SERVICES.COM
>     Name Server: DNS4.NAME-SERVICES.COM
>     Name Server: DNS5.NAME-SERVICES.COM
>   Registration Service Provided By: Namecheap.com
>
> % whois 192.31.186.20 |grep Name
>   NetName:        BLACK-LOTUS-COMMUNICATIONS

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have specifics on how to do this? I have looked through all the options in Namecheap and can't find anything. I should have just done domain and hosting with one company.